# Maven Failsafe Plugin: how to use the pre- and post-integration-test phases

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing, maven-failsafe-plugin

It is not completely clear to me how to best use the Maven Failsafe plugin for integration tests. My use case would be to test SQL queries against a local MySQL database.

I understand that the database should be started during the `pre-integration-test` phase, and shut down during the `post-integration-test`. 
But how do I specify that? Is there a command line I should put in my pom.xml? Or a method that I should annotate with a specific annotation?

Comment: Do you really need a MySQL or would it be sufficient to use an in memory database to test the queries?

Comment: Well, I'd rather understand how to use these two phases. So, a solution about a MySQL in-memory database would be interesting, but I am more interested in details about these two phases (and I already know about the use of H2 with a MySQL mode. And the only real MySQL in-memory database I found was not updated since 2006...)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the regular [built-in maven lifecycles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings) (jar, war...) the `pre-integration-test` and `post-integration-test` test phases are not bound to any maven plugin (ie. the default behavior of these phases is "do nothing"). If you want to setup and populate a database for the tests executed in the `integration-test` phase you need to bind a maven plugin doing that job to these phases.

The [SQL maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/) executes SQL script in a maven build. The configuration to bind this plugin to the `pre/post-integration-phase` is pretty straightforward:

In the `build`>`plugins` section of the pom.xml file, add the sql-maven-plugin

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <dependencies>
      <!-- include the JDBC driver dependency here -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>...</groupId>
        <artifactId>...</artifactId>
        <version>...</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- common plugin configuration -->
    <configuration>
      <driver>...</driver>
      <url>...</url>
      <username>...</username>
      <password>...</password>
      <!-- other parameters -->
    </configuration>

    <!-- the executions section binds the phases with some plugin goals and optional additional configuration parameters -->
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>execute</goal>
        </goals>
        <!-- specific configuration for this execution -->
        <configuration>
          <!-- Include here the SQL scripts to create the DB, inject some test data -->
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>execute</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <!-- Include here the SQL scripts to drop the database -->
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      [...]
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Great, it looks to be what I need. But then there is no way to launch a MySQL instance?

Comment: you may be able to start a mysql instance by using the exec plugin: http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/

Comment: I would suggest to use the following plugin: http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-mysql-maven-plugin/index.html.