# how do I run a selenium webdriver test before the regression suite in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a pre-requisite test that needs to be run before the Regression suite in jenkins. Please advice ? The pre-requisite tests does some configuration task before the regression could start. The environment that we are using is eclipse with TestNG, maven. The coding language used is java.

Comment: With what command did you run the tests?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `pre-integration-test` phase for running the configuration setups. Set it up with the `Maven Failsafe plugin` in the pom.xml. Refer to this - http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/ and [Maven Failsafe Plugin: how to use the pre- and post-integration-test phases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816407/maven-failsafe-plugin-how-to-use-the-pre-and-post-integration-test-phases)

---

Update with pom.xml sample build section.

```
<build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.21.0</version>
                <executions>

                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-test</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/PreTest.class</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>int-test</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/IntTest.class</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

---

Use this in the pre-integration-test configuration instead

```
<configuration>
    <suiteXmlFiles>
         <suiteXmlFile>
             src/test/resources/testng.xml(Path to testng xml) 
         </suiteXmlFile>
    </suiteXmlFiles>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. How would the pom.xml know which test is run as pre-requisite.

Comment: Updated with pom, modify as per your requirement

Comment: the name of my test is "CreateUsers.xml". Where do I put my test name in the above pom.xml to run it before the regression suite. Thanks

Comment: Is it .xml or .java file? Do clarify.

Comment: it's xml file. Thanks

Comment: Maybe this works, though this is not the ideal way of running tests. Better to let Maven use default configuration setups..